# programmatically close popup in ubuntu

Tags: scripting, ubuntu

How would I programmatically close a popup window in ubuntu?

I can do it using AppleScript on OSX:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "SketchUp"

        set frontmost to true
        keystroke return

    end tell
end tell
```

Now I'm looking for the equivalent on Ubuntu (version 10.10).

Answer (score 0):

You want to install the `wmctrl` package, then `man wmctrl` to see how to use it to select windows and ask them to close.  (I would give more detail but my Ubuntu VM is in the progress of upgrading to Natty.)

---

Ok, using backup of my VM since Natty and Parallels Tools don't talk to each other (yet):

```
jinx:1458 Z$ wmctrl -l
0x03e00037  0 jinx jinx {allbery} [~//lib]
0x03e00027  0 jinx jinx {allbery} [~]
0x03e00042  0 jinx jinx {allbery} [////xkb]
jinx:1459 Z$ wmctrl -c -i 0x03e00042
jinx:1460 Z$ _
```

By default (without `-i`) it matches against the window title.

Comment: Any luck with that Natty install? Care to post more details?

Comment: It's stopped waiting for me to sort out Parallels Tools.  I did copy the VM first and am bringing it back up now, having decided the Natty install isn't going to be usable in short order.